# Filling DataGridView Columns by selecting only one column value

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have DataGridView which is to be fill by three columns, `Profname, Profcharges and Profduedate`. I have converted Profname Column into a comboBox which is filled by all Profnames in the database. I want to fill Profcharges and Profduedate value automatically when any Profname is selecting form comboxBox.
my Code is:

```
try{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=AFZAL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=GIMS_LabInfo;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("SELECT PROFNAME, PROFCHARGES, PROFDUEDATE FROM PROFNAMES$", con);
    SqlDataReader reader;
    reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("TEST NAME", typeof(string));
    dt.Load(reader);

    Column1.ValueMember = "Profname";
    Column1.DisplayMember = "Profname";
    Column1.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you need to show or have a method [ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) read up on this link to learn how and from there you need to either bind that control to a sql query or pass that as a parameter to the database

Comment: here is a good post to read as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437635/connecting-2-dropdownlists-with-sqldatasource-filterexpression-inside-asprepeat